# UberApi history of vehicle

Tags: uber-api

I need to get a history of all my trips (more than 1000) in any parsable format.
For every single trip I need to know (**car**, **distance**, **cost**)

Unfortunatly:

- Uber app dosn't have an option to export history
- Uber site doesn't show a car of ride
- Uber recipts doesn't have an info about car
- Uber\history API also doesn't provide an info about car

Any suggestions would be appreciated

Comment: I don't believe there is a solution for what you are looking for. https://developer.uber.com/docs/riders/references/api/v1.2/history-get would be your best bet as it gives you many fields (distance, cost, etc.) but as you point out, there is not a car type field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, it is not possible to aggregate this data today.

Comment: found a way without distance. help.uber.com has a combobox with all data except distance. I scroll it till end, get everything throught FireFox console. Think it possible to merge this list with one get from the API to have a distance also